# Salesforce - Email Template Usage

Tags: salesforce, apex

Is there a quick method of reporting the usage of individual email templates within Salesforce on a Visualforce page?  The usage data is already calculated and posted on the individual email templates page.  I just need a method to query that data and report the usage for each email template on a summary page.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_emailtemplate.htm

> TimesUsed: Number of times this template has been used.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Subject, IsActive, TemplateType, LastUsedDate, TimesUsed
FROM EmailTemplate
WHERE TimesUsed > 0
ORDER BY TimesUsed DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Try this out too

```
SELECT Folder.Name, SUM(TimesUsed)
FROM EmailTemplate
WHERE IsActive = true
GROUP BY ROLLUP(Folder.Name)
```

(there will be 2 rows with blank folder name. First one will correspond to "unfiled public templates", second one will be a grand total row created because the `ROLLUP` function was used)